# How do you switch a field's widget to "Select" on a ModelForm in __init__?

Tags: django, forms

I need to make a form that uses a different widget for administrators than it uses for regular users. The admins can add a BillingAccount for any user on the site, while regular Users can only add one for themselves.

Here's my base form class definition:

```
class BillingAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BillingAccount
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            # Under most circumstances, the observer field should be hidden,
            # because it's automatically set up to be the current user.
            'observer': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

For admins, I want the Observer field to offer a dropdown of all the UserProfiles in the database, rather than hiding it. I've tried this:

```
def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None, initial=None,
            error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None, empty_permitted=False, instance=None,
            form_type='edit'):
    """
    This constructor changes up the widgets offered based on the form_type argument.
    """

    super(BillingAccountForm, self).__init__(
        data, files, auto_id, prefix, initial, error_class, label_suffix, empty_permitted, instance
    )

    if form_type == 'admin':
        self.fields['observer'].widget = widgets.Select(
            choices=UserProfile.objects.order_by('user__last_name', 'user__first_name').all()
        )
```

But for some odd reason it gives me a `<select>` list filled with blank options. I get the right *number* options, but they're all empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing this up, one of the "Similar Questions" that appeared in the sidebar gave me the answer. The issue was that switching the field's *widget* isn't enough: you also need to change the field's *queryset*.

```
def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None, initial=None,
            error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None, empty_permitted=False, instance=None,
            form_type='edit'):
    """
    This constructor changes up the widgets offered based on the form_type argument.
    """

    super(BillingAccountForm, self).__init__(
        data, files, auto_id, prefix, initial, error_class, label_suffix, empty_permitted, instance
    )

    if form_type == 'admin':
        self.fields['observer'].widget = widgets.Select()
        self.fields['observer'].queryset = UserProfile.objects.order_by('user__last_name', 'user__first_name')
```

I don't know *why* this is needed, though. The field already has a queryset attribute, so I haven't got a clue what re-assigning it is actually *doing* to fix the blank options.